# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Factory question

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to test a xml to excel converter in Java and I have the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Factory
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.onWorkbookCreate(XSSFWorkbook.java:475)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:232)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:226)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:214)
    at xmlToExcel.Converter.initXls(Converter.java:135)
    at xmlToExcel.Converter.getAndReadXml(Converter.java:60)
    at xmlToExcel.Converter.main(Converter.java:36)
```

The exception refers to the this line:

```
  workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

And here are my current jars

[image]

How can I solve this? Are there any conflicts in the jars?

EDIT 1: Here is the code for the method which initialises the POI workbook and writes the header row

```
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    Font boldFont = workbook.createFont();
    boldFont.setBold(true);
    style.setFont(boldFont);
    style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
    rowNum = 0;
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(SUBSTANCE_NAME_COLUMN);
    cell.setCellValue("Substance name");
    cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

The exception references the first line, the creation of the workbook.

Comment: Show us the relevant code, in your question.

Comment: `apache poi 5.2.1` cannot be used together with `poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar`. It needs to be used with `poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.1.jar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While using `apache poi` **never** mix jars from different versions. See [faq-N10204](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10204).

So when used `apache poi` version `5.2.1` **all** `apache poi` jars needs to be from that version. So in your case `apache poi 5.2.1` cannot be used together with `poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar`. It needs to be used with either `poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.1.jar` or `poi-ooxml-full-5.2.1.jar`.

To avoid conflicts, furthermore all jars from not matching versions should be excluded from class path while running `apache poi` code.

So in your case using `apache poi 5.2.1` there should not be any `poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar` in class path additional to either `poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.1.jar` or `poi-ooxml-full-5.2.1.jar`. Also `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` should not be in class path while using `apache poi 5`.  The `ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar` was the former version of `poi-ooxml-full-5.*.jar` and also cannot be used together with `apache poi 5`.

Comment: Thank you , I did as you said and now the program had no more exceptions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. That saved lot of time for me. I appreciate your help.